# Get JSON data from a request and craft a JSON response using Java Jersey and Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jersey

I'm a beginner trying to learn about RESTful API in Java. I have created a Dynamic Web project in Eclipse and tried to receive JSON data in request.

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestAPI {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String sayHello(User user) {
        String name = user.getName();
        return name;
    }
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class User{
    private String name;
    public User() {}
    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String s) {
        this.name = s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String toString(){
          return "{\"name\": "+name+"}";
       }
}
```

In this code, I have tried to create a class User which only have one attribute name. I'm trying to send the name as JSON in request and retrieve the name from JSON.

> HTTP Status 500 - javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing
>   object from entity stream
>   error.
>   Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Import section is

```
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
```

Comment: Whats the json request you are sending to this endpoint?

Comment: Hi, I'm sending {"name" : "midnight"}.

Comment: try with {"user": {"name" : "midnight"} }

Comment: Still 
"HTTP Status 500 - javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error deserializing object from entity stream." error

Comment: {"name" : "midnight"} should work. Seems like a problem with some library.

Comment: I'm using Jersey 2.27 and all imported libraries are edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all the xml tags from your POJO and run.

Like this:

```
class User{
    private String name;
    public void setName(String s) {
        this.name = s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String toString(){
          return "{\"name\": "+name+"}";
       }
}
```

Request JSON:

```
{"name" : "Your Name"}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Then there must be some jars which are conflicting.